# Lombok+spring boot java 8: Handling list creation and updation in class annotated with lombok builder

Tags: java, lombok

Lombok version: 1.18.6

My use case is to add a list of objects received to class variable list at runtime within an object which has @Builder annotation as defined in below example:

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class Source {

@Singular("multiple")
private List<MultipleSource> multiple;
}
```

From DAO class, I will receive a list of values for multiple which I am interested to map to multiple list variable within Source:

```
 Source(Source.builder().multiple().build());
```

when I try to create a list with `new` and it to the builder, it fails compilation as expected.

How to create or map the list received to the class variable list?

Comment: Why do you call the constructor of Source with the result of the Source builder (which should be a perfectly good and usable Source object by itself)?

Comment: becasue it is a hierarchy of classes, source is variable in another class. From the top level class builder, source has to be built and from source multiple list has to be built.

Comment: Using the same singular name as the field itself makes this a little tricky (you get an overload in your builder), but it does work. You can pass either a single `MultipleSource` object in, or a `Collection<? extends MultiSource>` in, either way will work. I'm not sure what you're actually asking; does this help?

Comment: @rzwitserloot, yes I understand that singular annotation concept but my question is value for variable 'multiple' is dynamic, from the received I will have to createt the 'MultipleSource' Object, it can be single or multiple but it has to go in list, if I create list with 'new' compilation fails, how to dynamically, at runtime I will iterate through the received data and add it to list 'multiple', does this make question better understandable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.. get what you're asking :(

Comment: alright @rzwitserloot,
1) there are some 10 variables within Multiplesource object.
2) I will receive 50 variables from DAO
3) I have to make 5 MultipleSource objects from this received variables
4) insert/add those objects in the list
5) pass the list to builder, 

this is what I am looking at to achieve. But i can't create list using 'new' keyword, compilation error occurs when i pass teh list to builder.

Comment: Why wouldn'y you be able to write 'new ArrayList()'? That has nothing to do with lombok, and you can pass an actual list to the builder just fine (after all, a List<MultipleSource> is a Collection<? extends MultipleSource> and therefore something you can pass to the multiple() method.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, yes it is working. I tried many a times but it was throwing compil;ation error but now it works. My bad! Thanks for answering patiently